# How to send image as an HTTP response using TcpClient

Tags: c#, image, http-headers, tcpclient, tcplistener

In my job I have server and clients (several devices) connected in to the same network.

Clients contacts with server using their web-browser.

Server is running a C# program that uses `TcpListener` to receive requests from browsers.

I'm trying to send an image through `TcpClient`to client device but this is the result:

[image: this is the result]

**I'v tried:**

- Read image file as `String`
- Read image file as `Byte[]`

After some searches inside Chrome Developer console i found an error 
`net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`.

i don't know why `Content-Length: length-in-byte` value isn't correct even through `new FileInfo(Target).Length`.

**Code I use:**

```
TcpListener Listener = new TcpListener(local_address, 9090);
Listener.Start();

TcpClient client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

string target = HeaderKeys.GetValue("target"); /* image file in the request*/ 
string mime_type = MimeType.Extract(target); /* mime-type of the file */

byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(target);

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ns);
// response header
writer.Write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
writer.Write($"Content-Type: {mime_type}");
writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
writer.Write("Content-Length: " + content.Length);
writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
writer.Write(content);
writer.Flush();
client.Close();
```

**I'v tried**

- `NetworkStream` directly.
- reading image file in `MemoryStream` and `NetworkStream` to write.
- reading image file as byte[] and convert it to Base64.

Comment: You should show the code for the listener and client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because of `StreamWriter`

I've solved the issue using this code:

```
    TcpClient client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    Stream s = client.GetStream();

    byte[] file_content = File.ReadAllBytes(file);

    StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();

    header.Append("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
    header.Append($"Content-Type: {mime_type}\r\n");
    header.Append($"Content-Length: {file_content .Length}\r\n\n");

    byte[] h = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header.ToString());

    s.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
    s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    s.Flush();

    client.Close();
```

Comment: I do not understand your code. Can you explain the 'content' variable used in s.Write, how it is formed ?    also I do not see how you have used variable 'h' and 'file_content' and 'b' .  can you published the full code related to this.